# I recieve 'jsonschema.exceptions.UndefinedTypeCheck: Type 'string' is unknown to this type checker' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema

I need to validate a schema of the JSON, which I receive from API request. For this, I'm creating some test script.

```
    def get_request():
    r = requests.post(*some request*)
    return r

    """The schema which needs to be validated:"""

    tc = TypeChecker()
    my_json = get_request()[0]
    schema = {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "id": {"type": "number"},
            'name': {"type": "string"},
            "launchAlias": {"type": "string"},
            "imsGameType": {"type": "string"},
            "liveGameType": {"type": "string"},
            "tableColor": {"type": "string"},
            "dedicated": {"type": "boolean"},
            "status": {"type": "string"},
            "language": {"type": "string"},
            "languageFlagImageUrl": {"type": "string"},
            "dynamicImageUrl": {"type": "string"},
            "asaAlternativeImage": {"type": "string"},
            "dealer": {"type": "array"},
            "dealerName": {"type": "string"},
            "dealerPictureUrl": {"type": "string"},
            "asaCompliant": {"type": "string"},
            "platforms": {"type": "array"},
            "playerCount": {"type": "array"},
        },
    }


    """Schema validation"""

    tc.is_type(instance=my_json["name"], type='string')
```

I expect to receive output would be simple 'Process finished with exit code 0'
Tried several variants for other instances like "type=string/str/number/integer/array etc." Always get same error

But I always get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\vvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonschema_types.py", line 91, in is_type
>     fn = self._type_checkers[type]
>     File "C:\Users\vvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrsistent_pmap.py", line 71, in **getitem**
>       return PMap._getitem(self._buckets, key)
>     File "C:\Users\vvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrsistent_pmap.py", line 68, in _getitem
>       raise KeyError(key)
>   KeyError: 'string'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/vvel/PycharmProjects/untitled/asd.py", line 58, in 
>       validate_object()
>     File "C:/Users/vvel/PycharmProjects/untitled/asd.py", line 54, in validate_object
>      tc.is_type(instance=my_json["name"], type='string')
>     File "C:\Users\vvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonschema_types.py", line 93, in is_type
>       raise UndefinedTypeCheck(type)
>   jsonschema.exceptions.UndefinedTypeCheck: Type 'string' is unknown to this type checker

Answer (score 0):

It seems highly unlikely you actually want to use `TypeChecker` directly.

You have an instance and a schema.

You probably just mean to use `jsonschema.validate(instance, schema)`, or `validator = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(schema); validator.validate(instance)`.